# ​[Face] it: this tag needs some work

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I'm not convinced we should burninate it, so I'll bypass that criteria for now (so don't go burninating the tag).

We have a [face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/face) tag. It is... somewhat of a mess. Here's the tag wiki:

> A face is an elementary surface geometry. Faces are used in 3D modelling to define meshes

And the full tag wiki:

> A [face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(geometry)) is an elementary surface geometry. A face is defined by three (sometimes four) vertices or the indices from a vertices array or collection.
> Faces are used in 3D modelling, for example to define faceted [boundary representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_representation).
>
> **Note:** Use this tag for questions related to *face geometries*, do **not** use this tag for questions related to *face recognition* (use `face-recognition` instead).

Unfortunately... that didn't work.

There's

- [A handful of questions tagged with it containing "facebook"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bface%5Dfacebook)
- A number of questions tagged with it about the interaction with AI and faces (i.e., face swap, etc.)
- 30 questions (as of writing) tagged with both the [face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/face) tag and the [face-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/face-recognition) tag
- And, some about actual geometric faces

This is... not an ideal tag currently. While in theory, it refers to one thing, in reality it refers to a number of topics. I, personally, lean towards multiple tags, such as [geometric-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometric-face), etc., but... I don't know.

What should we do with this tag?

---

Note to editors: the zero-width space at the start of the title is to bypass the "no tags starting titles" restriction as... I'd like a pun in the title.

Comment: no tags starting titles" restriction...Is this a meta rule  or a SO one?

Comment: @TheMaster Both, annoying. See [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ll0XH3f.png)

Comment: "let's [face] it" would've worked too

Comment: [tag:face-geometry] or [tag:geometry-face].

Comment: [tag:face-surface].

Comment: [tag:gemetry-face] (and all other variant's) are imho not needed. Alone they desribe a concept which isn't on-topic by itself and for all other use-cases (rendering, geometry processing), it's probably not necessary to tag with the geometry type involved.

Comment: Yeah I find it difficult to think of scenarios where you would be specifically asking questions on Stack Overflow about faces in 3D geometry. Certainly not to the point where it needs to be a tag. So even if it would be disambiguated... still not useful. A tag face-recognition might be slightly more useful.

Comment: The term is also sometimes used in GUI programming, ie "buttonface". Various GUI/RAD tools have properties called "buttonface" etc.

Comment: Also apparently "front-face" is a common term in CSS.

Comment: @Gimby That was how the tag was supposed to be used and in low level graphics programming it's not an uncommon thing. Some libs like OpenGL use it all the time though the API functions are called "vertex-something" and you state the corners of the face.

Comment: One more thing overlooked by initial analysis: [quite a bit of question seems to be about face detection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bface%5D+detection+-%5Bface-detection%5D+-%5Bface-recognition%5D)

Comment: @cocomac, what part of burnination criteria seems controversial for you regarding this tag (especially once all human-face-related question are re-tagged properly)?

Comment: A facet, if you will, of the problem here could be described as "common English words with very specific, jargony applications in very narrow fields of endeavor." I'm trying to think of other examples, but I suppose I'm just not into any exotic interests. But I guess I learned something about geometry faces. Namely, that they exist.

Comment: @MrBoJangles well now look at the "mesh" tag :) The next step up on the ladder. And a tag I find more useful and far less ambiguous in the context of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The tag is indeed too ambiguous and misused. I propose that the tag is burninated and replaced with a new tag [geometrical-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometrical-face).

- Re-tag questions about geometry or low level graphics etc with [geometrical-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometrical-face).
- Re-tag all questions related to face recognition with [face-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/face-recognition).
- Re-tag all questions related to Facebook with [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook).
- Questions not fitting in the above 3 categories should have the tag removed.

Comment: One more thing often appearing with [tag:face] tag is a [tag:face-detection] questions. So probably it should be added to the list.

Comment: @markalex I don't see how that is any different from [tag:face-recognition]. In fact recognition and detection are synonyms. Maybe these tags should be merged? I'm far from a domain expert on that topic.

Comment: No, they shouldn't be merged. And those are different things: recognition - identification of user (or arbitrary human) based on image of their face, detection - detection of presence of human face in the image.

Comment: I suggest not retagging with [tag:geometrical-face]. Better use the appropriate graphics API, or something more generic like [tag:geometry]. Different geometric elements don't need separate tags

Comment: @markalex I still don't get why that merits two different tags, let alone how we are supposed to make people pick the right tag.

Comment: @BDL The advantage of having "face" somewhere in the tag name is that the tag search system will then suggest it as soon as someone types "face".

Comment: @Lundin: But then you also need vertex, edge, polyline, volume (which exists and collides with sound volume), triangle, quad, ..., that's not helpful at all. Especially because it's unlike that there is any question about the geometry itself (and not the code that api/library that handles geometry) that is on-topic on SO.

Comment: @BDL It's 100% likely that there are such questions, as we can already find plenty from the history of what's currently tagged [tag:face]. Yes these are about graphics API/library but that API/library in turn often has functions directly corresponding to various geometric shapes. OpenGL is one such example. How is it unreasonable for someone having a question about the function `glVertex` to not tag their question `vertex`? If we don't provide tags for geometric shapes, then the alternative is to provide a tag for every function in every graphics lib out there. _That_ is not helpful.

Comment: Whereas in my example [tag:opengl] and [tag:vertex] together would narrow down the question. [tag:vertex] is of course a useless tag stand-alone, but there is no requirement that every tag should be useful stand-alone. Also _we already have the geometric shape tags_! Like it or not.

Comment: @Lundin: Imho, adding vertex to an OpenGL question is pretty useless. It's on the same level as adding [tag:web] to a [tag:php] question. Yes, it's used, but it doesn't add any relevant information.

Comment: @BDL Then how exactly would you tag a question regarding [this family of functions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=subroutines-glvertex-subroutine)?

Comment: just OpenGL and the programming language which you are using. Maybe a OpenGL version tag if your problem is specific to a version. You are never an expert in just one function of an API. But if people think that the tag is needed, go ahead, I'm not invested enough to argue about it.

Comment: @Lundin: Probably opengl-compat, since those aren't used with forward contexts (you'd use VAOs instead)